# Android ConstraintLayout Group - Can setPadding be used on a group of views?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-support-library, android-constraintlayout

I'd like to add padding programmatically to a group of views inside a ConstraintLayout. I'm trying the new features like Group, Chain,...
But with group I could only set visibility

Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't do that with group, you have to do it using guidelines
In your xml, define these guidelines

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/padding_start_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/padding_end_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Now, say for example you have a "match_parent" edit text,

So what you do is(not using strings.xml for demo),

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:hint="Enter name here"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/padding_end_guideline"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/padding_start_guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/task_label" />
```

I guess, you understand the point. Instead of using

**app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"**

you use,

**app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/padding_start_guideline"**

and likewise replace

**app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"**

with

**app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/padding_end_guideline"**